# Moral issues in cyber technology

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-technology, moral-realism, computer-ethics

Is anyone of deontology or utilitarianism adequate to handle moral issues in cyber technology? Or do we need some other theory?

Comment: Please see [SEP, Ethics of Artificial Intelligence and Robotics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-ai/) for general reading. Questions here are expected to be more specific.

Comment: @Conifold Good link, but surprising sketchy on ethics and [superintelligence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-ai/#Sing), e.g. "*Arguments for risk from superintelligence say that rationality and morality are entirely independent dimensions*" and "*These discussions of risk are usually not connected to the general problem of ethics under risk.*"

Answer (score 1):

Where AI becomes competent enough that people can become dependent on it and vulnerable to manipulation 'ethics of care' would be pertinent.  Good luck to that though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics_of_care

> Carol Gilligan,
> who is considered the originator of the ethics of care, criticized the
> application of generalized standards as "morally problematic, since it
> breeds moral blindness or indifference"

Comment: can deontology or utilitarianism deal with it?

Comment: It would be interesting to clarify exactly how care ethics' claim goes further than utilitarianism and deontology.  Maybe it's a basic participatory position.